# Get access token after login authorization code - Dataverse

Tags: .net-core, token, dataverse

I am trying to connect to dataverse to call web APIs for CRUD operations.

I created ASP.net core web application that takes me to interactive login page on crm dynamics
This is my sample code

```
var authBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                           .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                           .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                           .Build();
            var scope = resource + "/.default";
            string[] scopes = { scope };


            AuthenticationResult token =
                authBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

After login on azure side, it redirects me to my application and pass code in query string

How do I get access token from the returned code? please send a clear code as I tried to find example to follow.

I could find solid code to follow, I expect access token from authorization code that returned in query string using C# core